# Having a problem with underbrace in LaTex

Tags: equations, underbrace

I am trying to write an equation in LaTex and want to add text under the underbraced part, but the top part starts to split further and further as i write. i want to get rid of the gaps that are between ,,+ j_uA^u )"
[image: image of the problem]

Comment: Sample codes with the issues helps more than a screenshot and guessing.

Comment: Use `\mathclap` in the "subscript" part of the `\underbrace`. This is similar to what is mentioned here: [How to force equation to be closer to the sum operator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67647/5764)